# Android сохранить изображения в кэш

Tags: java, android, picasso

Передо мной строит следующая задача,  мне приходит  json с ссылкой на рисунком и дата создания рисунка. Мне надо закэшировать рисунок на телефоне и подгружать его с телефона, если дата создания рисунка меняет(меняется рисунок), мне надо рисунок перезаписать кэш, на данный момент я использую Picasso, он каждый раз подгружает из сети(((  Как мне это реализовать?

Picasso.with(context)
    .load(url)
    .placeholder(R.drawable.user_placeholder)
    .error(R.drawable.user_placeholder_error)
    .into(imageView);

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. Вбиваем в гугл

> [picasso android cache](https://www.google.ru/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=picasso%20android%20cache)

2. Идём по первой ссылке на [en-SO](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30686992/3212712)

   ```
   Picasso.with(context)
   .load(imageUrl)
   .networkPolicy(NetworkPolicy.OFFLINE)
   .into(imageView, new Callback() {
       @Override
       public void onSuccess() {

       }

       @Override
       public void onError() {
           //Try again online if cache failed
           Picasso.with(context)
                   .load(posts.get(position).getImageUrl())
                   .error(R.drawable.header)
                   .into(imageView, new Callback() {
               @Override
               public void onSuccess() {

               }

               @Override
               public void onError() {
                   Log.v("Picasso","Could not fetch image");
               }
           });
       }
   });
   ```